# SSRS : How to Repeat one row of table header on each page and other header just on first page

Tags: reporting-services

I have table with 2 rows of header, and I needed repeat first  row in all the pages but second row only in first page. If I set the properies "RepeatOnNewPage" in the First row only, SSRS show the error: "The TablixMember must have the same value set for the RepeatOnNewPage property as those following or preceding the dynamic TablixMember"

If I set this property in the all (2) rows of header - all ok, but I need only second row to appear only on First page

How to repeat only second row on first page and first row on all page?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this expression on the Hidden property for the header row you only want to show on the first page.

```
=IIf(Globals!PageNumber = 1, False, True)
```

If the page number is 1, Hidden is false (showing), otherwise true (hidden).

Comment: page number works only in header and footer not in body(Table)

Comment: Forgot about that! Sorry.

Comment: Are you doing any page breaking based on a group, by chance? You could check the value of the group and set the hidden property. If the first group value is consistent from one report run to another. Probably not the best idea I have ever come up with.

Comment: No I an not doing any page breaking on group,I just want to repeat 1st header to all pages and 2nd only to first page

Answer (score 0):

Create a group based on a field value that never changes and put the second row of the header in the group header. Make the table header repeat on all pages and the group header not repeat on all pages.

Comment: In this way the group header will come above the table header,which i don't want,the second header should come below the first header

Comment: @Khushboo any answer you get?